# Is it possible to let bash to detect compiling error in C?

Tags: c, bash

I have a tricky requirement:

I need to use bash to compile 100 programs, say `1.c`, `2.c`, `3.c` ... `100.c`, I want to keep those c programs which was compiled successfully and **remove c programs which compilation errors**.

Up to now I can only achieve the goal that compiling those 100 programs but I really have **no idea how to detect whether there was failed compilation in these 100 programs**.

Comment: The return code of the compiler should give you a hint.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I am trying working on a solution based on your idea.

Comment: I updated my answer with the full script.

Answer (score 7):

Just check whether the return code is nonzero, and delete the file if it is nonzero. The return code is stored in the shell variable `$?` after running the compiler.

Here is the long form of what such a script would look like.

```
for i in {1..99}; 
do
    gcc ${i}.c 2> /dev/null > /dev/null

    if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then
        rm ${i}.c
    fi

done
```

As user268396, the the middle part can be shortened to the following.

```
gcc ${i}.c || rm ${i}.c
```

The use of the short-circuiting operator `||` will ensure that the latter statement will only run if the former statement fails (ie, exits with a non-zero return code).

Comment: You can simplify this further: use `cc $sourcefile || rm $sourcefile`.

Comment: @user268396, Good point. I'll edit the answer to show both the long form and the short form.

Comment: I think since bash 3.x, you don't need to fork for `seq` any more, you can just use `{1..99}`

Comment: @chw21, Good point. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for the error code that the compiler returns, it is stored in `$?`

```
for f in *.c; do
    t=${f%.c}      # Strip the .c from the source file name
    gcc -o $t $f   # Try to compile
    if [[ "$?" -ne 0 ]]; then
        rm $f
    fi
done
```